# Can you set targets for multiple outputs in a TensorFlow/Keras sequential network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm looking for a way to essentially rank outputs of a neural net. For my specific case I am trying to make a NN which generates a relevant permutation of the alphabet based off of an array of letter frequencies. I think I would need to be able to specify the target values for all the outputs.

The official documentation states:

> it could be either Numpy array(s) or TensorFlow tensor(s). It should be consistent with x (you cannot have Numpy inputs and tensor targets, or inversely).

if my input vector is just a large tensor, could my value for y be in the form of [25,3,1,6,17,12...]? Otherwise how could I specify the rankings of the outputs?

Comment: I'm not completly sure what you want to achieve. Isn't your "ranking" just a feature to learn?

Comment: The ranking is supposed to indicate the order of a permutation. I just need a way for a network to be able to uniquely represent any permutation of the alphabet without needing 26! outputs

Comment: It would only need 26 outputs wouldn't it? Unless you don't want repeats? In which case you'd have to come up with a way of teaching it that, probably by just factoring it into your cost function?

Comment: Yes. That's the way I'm approaching it now. I have 26 outputs each corresponding with a single letter. The output array sorted by size of each element would correspond to a permutation. My problem is that from reading the documentation for tf.keras.models.fit() I can't work out how to actually implement a target ranking system

Comment: Hmm the sorting seems something you can do when postprocessing your output. Changing the outputs order is nothing a network has to do.

Comment: Output could be a 2D array with softmax along the rows. Each row is a letter